# comparison of two integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Let $n \in N$.

How to compare two integrals:
$$
I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)^n dt \quad \text{and} \quad I_2=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)^n dt\,\, ?
$$

I've beet trying to compare them for some particular $n$. It seems, that $I_1>I_2$ for $n-\text{even}$ and $I_2>I_1$ for odd $n$.

Help me please to prove this statement for any $n\in N$.

Thank you.

Comment: For $I_1$, try to split the interval as $[0,\infty)=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} [n\pi, (n+1)\pi) $.

Comment: For even $n$ we have $f_n\geq 0$. Hence 
$I_1\geq I_2$ in this case, actually $I_1=+\infty$ in this case. Here 
$$f_n(x) = \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n$$